# Inverted colours in Kivy ToggleButtons

Tags: kivy, kivy-language

Have a set of ToggleButtons where the general foreground colour is green and the general background colour is black. Then I use

```
background_down: 'btn_prs_grn.png'
on_state: self.color = [0,0,0,1] if self.state == 'down' else [0,1,0,1]
```

To make (I thought) the active button black-on-green, but what I get is more like slightly-darker-green-on-normal-green.

I assume this is because the button (label) colours are blended/tinted/whatever-it's-called together.

**Edit**: here is a photo of the buttons.

[image]

Left button normal, right button down. It is actually possible to make out the text "White" on the right button, in a slightly darker shade of green than the normal one.

What is the easiest way to achieve black-on-green? I understand I can draw on the canvas myself but is there a simpler method?

Answer (score 1):

## Output - ToggleButton

[image: Img01]

## Button

In kv file, set `background_normal: ''`

[background_color](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.button.html#kivy.uix.button.Button.background_color)

> ```
> background_color
> ```
>
> Background color, in the format (r, g, b, a).
>
> This acts as a multiplier to the texture colour. ***The default
>   texture is grey, so just setting the background color will give a
>   darker result. To set a plain color, set the background_normal to
>   ''.***
>
> The background_color is a ListProperty and defaults to [1, 1, 1, 1].

[background_normal](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.button.html#kivy.uix.button.Button.background_normal)

> ```
> background_normal
> ```
>
> Background image of the button used for the default graphical
>   representation when the button is not pressed.
>
> background_normal is a StringProperty and defaults to
>   ‘atlas://data/images/defaulttheme/button’.

Comment: I actually had that line also, and it does not seem to make any difference whether I use it or not.

Comment: Sorry, I'm getting a bit mixed up here. I have a couple of similar but slightly different sets of buttons. Adding the line `background_normal: ''` to the one I asked about above messes up the "normal" state but does not fix the "down" state.

Comment: Could you please update your post with a print screen of ToggleButton's colour?

Comment: I would have included it from the beginning if it had been easy. I'm running it on a Rpi with only a touch screen. But it seems pretty clear that the "problem" is the text is not in the foreground colour (black) but in image colour+foreground colour. I need a way to put the text above (in front of) the image, or something equivalent.

Comment: So in your picture, is the green button active ("down")? And is it an image, or just green background?

Comment: The green button is active ("down").

Comment: I tried to take a photo but it didn't work. The difference is very slight between background green and text green, on the active button. But I have experiemented with different foreground colours, and am pretty sure it is the way I describe it.

Comment: The darker colour could be from custom Button's setting in your app because ToggleButton inherits from Button.

Comment: But I am setting the colour to black, in the code in the question. This seems to work fine since it becomes a slightly lighter shade when I change it to white. Also, I do not have any custom Button settings (I think).